# How do I change the location of .g.dart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the `json_serializable` package to auto-generate boilerplate codes. But it seems this package for `build_runner` forces us to locate the generated files in `FILENAME.g.dart` as we need to specify the `part 'FILENAME.g.dart'`. I tried to change the `FILENAME` to the location I want generated files to be located, but it didn't work. I don't want the generated files to be within the same folder where the original files are located. How do I customize it?

Comment: Manually modify the part file and change the parent file's path. Don't forget to update the part file's path in the parent file.

Comment: @rickimaru That could be a solution. But it's tedious to do all that jobs whenever editing and running the build_runner.